# Drop down menu behind div

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I am using Montana template on Wordpress and I have no idea why my dropdown menu is hide behind the main slider...

Here is the link of the test environment: http://evolutionescaperooms.com/dev/

[image]

Even if I put ul tag to z-index : 99999 or position : absolute, still doesn't work... But if you close and reopen the menu, the dropdown will be above the slider, without any reason...

Anyone got a quick fix please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an overflow issue not a z-index issue. The `.navigation` div has `overflow: hidden;` in its css. This is cropping any child elements that overflow its boundaries.

When you open and close the navigation it toggles the overflow to `overflow: initial` via Javascript. Hence why it only works after the menu is opened and closed.

Original CSS:

```
.navigation {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    overflow: hidden; /* Preventing overflowing popup menu from showing */
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 40px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}
```

Update to:

```
.navigation {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 40px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}
```

Comment: You saved my day ! I was looking everywhere but didn't think about that... Thanks !